# Creating a page to display several content types

Tags: 7, theming

I have a website to build that requires several quite long pages, each containing several sections with quite different content in each.

A content type for each page isn't going to work as some sections would need to contain several entries, to be displayed as a slider.

So, I think, I need to create each section as a different content type and my problem becomes displaying several of these on the same page?

How can I display several content types on the same page?

Or maybe I could create a category for each page and add the types to those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Views module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) might help you for this purpose. It is highly configurable, and it allows you to display several items on a single page. Other modules can add functionality, like the [Views Slideshow module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow).

Learning how to use Views takes some time, but there are many Views tutorials available in the web. A possible starting point might be this one:

- https://dev.acquia.com/blog/a-totally-beginner-tutorial-to-views-for-drupal-7/22/01/2016/9576

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels)  and [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) to make it. With Panels you can create a new page with the regions you need, and with Views you can create blocks which can list nodes.

So you create Views of each content type you need and put it with Panels.

Answer (score -1):

[Views module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) is what you need.

Edit:

With this module, you can customize the presentation of the content (and different content types) of your Drupal site in many different ways on a single page and in many other ways. The fact that the module is so flexible, it can be assumed as "advanced web based query builder" and hence also makes it that confusing and complex at the same time.

It can take some time to grasp the whole concept of views as the other answer illustrates, however you can start using it to fit your simple needs in no time. You can follow some tutorials and make use of it in no time. The link that the other answer has provided looks like a good place to start. Here's [one more](https://www.drupalgardens.com/documentation/views/tutorial).

Comment: Although answer points on the right direction it would be nice to give some explanation about what is Views and why it shouldbe used.

Comment: @tunic Agreed, and updated.